# User control buttons actions

Tags: javascript, genexus

I have this user control:

```
function Test1($)
{
    this.Width;
    this.Height;

    this.show = function()
    {
        ///UserCodeRegionStart:[show] (do not remove this comment.)
        var buffer = "..." +
                    "<button onclick=\"alertfuncfora()\"> click </button>" + 
                    "...";

        this.setHtml(buffer);

        ...

        ///UserCodeRegionEnd: (do not remove this comment.)
    }
    ///UserCodeRegionStart:[User Functions] (do not remove this comment.)

    ///UserCodeRegionEnd: (do not remove this comment.):
}

...

function alertfuncfora(){
    alert("ola ola");
}
```

But every time the button is clicked the page is refreshed after I close the pop up window.
I don't want to refresh the page every time I click in a button. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your button is probably inside a `<form>` tag.

Use `return false;` to prevent the refresh.

Something like this:

`<button onclick="alertfuncfora(); return false;"> click </button>`

Comment: Thanks @AndreiHodecker! It works :)
How do you know that? You read it somewhere? If you could tell me where you learn that I will appreciate. I don't know how to get that kind of information, and I have read a lot of thinks in the wiki about user controls.

Comment: Nice it worked @marcpt! Since you made a simple user control, everythig else is just javascript and HTML. If wish to learn more about user controls, I strongly suggest to download some of them in the marketshare and see how it works, the Artech's documentation is kind of basic and looking the source-code of others really helped me when I needed.